# How change height of line's strike-through

Tags: html, css

Yesterday with one friend discuss for change height of line about strike-through.
Today searching on [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/s) of CSS says :

```
The HTML Strikethrough Element (<s>) renders text with a strikethrough, or a line through it.
Use the <s> element to represent things that are no longer relevant or no longer accurate. 
However, <s> is not appropriate when indicating document edits; 
for that, use the <del> and <ins> elements, as appropriate.
```

And seems that `<s>` accept all reference of CSS but not function on height.

**CSS:**

```
s {
    color: red;
    height: 120px
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
<br /><br />
<s >Strikethrough</s>
```

There is a simpler [demo on JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a68mnb13/) and you see that not change the height of line....

There is a alternative solution or I wrong on CSS?

**EXPLAIN WITH IMAGE**

[image]

Comment: @Harry Already read this question and not say the height of line.

Comment: Oh Ok. In that case does Hashem's answer address your query? If not, could you please clarify more on which height you are looking for?

Comment: I want to change the height of the line that is above the line.

Comment: Now I put the image....

Comment: @MirkoCianfarani It seems I misunderstood the question; To answer this I should note that it's not possible to handle the line itself in order to style it, etc. Thus, you have to fake the effect like what Mikode has done.

Comment: There are also more alernative solution... how Harpem 
Mikode is a solution but after I put accepted answer

Comment: @MirkoCianfarani if you change the **height** of the **.through** class in my answer and adjust the **top** % value to suit your needs it does exactly what you want.

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/mikode/pn3npjao/) - here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way to handle this is to use a pseudo element to simulate the desired behavior.

```
 s {
    color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
  }
s:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-bottom: 3px solid;
}
```

The border inherits text-color and you gain full control over your styling, including hover effects.

[JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/81hb7ech/)

Answer (score 4):

I've wanted to do this before and came up with this:

```
<span class="strike">
    <span class="through"></span>
    Strikethrough
</span>
```

and:

```
.strike {
    position:relative;
    color:red;
}

.strike .through {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:1px;
    background: red;
    /* position of strike through */
    top:50%;
}
```

[JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mikode/xwym515p/)

and if you want multiple strike throughs you can use something like this:

[JS Fiddle - multi strikes](http://jsfiddle.net/mikode/ppvae9ru/2/)

Comment: the position from the top doesn't have to be in % though. you could set the line-height of **.strike** in pixels and use a pixel value for the **.through** top position.

Comment: Good job Mikode, I'd suggest having a look at `currentColor` keyword which helps to color the *line* based on the value of `color` property. Also adding a negative margin make it look better: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/xwym515p/2/

Comment: Perfect solution good for you....

Comment: yeah currentColor is good but its browser support is poor and this way you have complete control over colours should you wish to have different coloured strike throughs. Your **margin-top** addition seems strange though as is negates the % given to the **top** value already given.

Answer (score 1):

This is my alternative version.

```
s {
        color: red;
        position: relative;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

s:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: -10px;
    content: " ";
    background: red;
    height: 1px;
}
```

**[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a68mnb13/2/)**

Comment: mmm good alternative but with css work better 
s:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 5px;
    content: " ";
    background: red;
    height: 8px;
}

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  s {
     color: red;
     text-decoration: none;
     background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 7px,#cc1f1f 7px,#cc1f1f 12px,transparent 9px);
     height: 100px
  }
```

Comment: This alternative solution work but have to change "transparent"